# Android LruCache (Android 3.1) thread safety

Tags: android, thread-safety, lru

Is the new Android class [LruCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html) thread safe? The java doc says:

> This class is thread-safe. Perform multiple cache operations atomically by synchronizing on the cache:

```
   synchronized (cache) {
     if (cache.get(key) == null) {
         cache.put(key, value);

   }}
```

Did they mean to say NOT thread-safe? Why would one have to synchronize if the class is thread safe?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Doesn't matter whether the class is thread-safe or not. If you use multiple operations you may still need to synchronize. Depends on how you use it.

```
if (cache.get(key) == null)
{
  //at this point you think there is no such value in the cache
  //but another thread might have just added one between executing
  //those two lines of code
  cache.put(key, value);
}
```